# List custom taxonomy as navigation - taxonomy pages with all it's posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have no idea how to do this and really need your help please …

First I created a custom-post-template called "wr_event" - then I added a custom taxonomy (like categories) to this post-template!

```
register_taxonomy(
    'Type of event',
    'wr_event',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'event_type',
        'label' => 'Types',
        'singular_label' => 'Type',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => true)
);
```

I did all that in my `functions.php` file. The "types" I created in my taxonomy in the wp-backend right now are "Lectures", "Workshops", "Festivals".

If I create a post (event) and assign it to a "category" (taxonomy) I get this url `localhost.com/lectures/my-post-title` and the `single-wr_event.php` template is used.

This is already a big step towards what I finally want.

What I don't know is how I can now kind of create `pages` for my taxonomies like it automatically works for posts and categories?

e.g. I said I have this right now:
`localhost.com/lectures/my-post-title`

but when I just enter `localhost.com/lectures/` I want all the posts assigned to this taxonomie listed. And I'd like to add a navigation in my header that lists all taxonomies I created just like 'wp_list_categories'.

Any ideas on how to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the file taxonomy-event_type.php. That will be used when you use the url /?event_type=lectures or /event_type/lectures.

You can use wp_list_categories by adding 'taxonomy' => 'event_type' to the arguments (see http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Display_Terms_in_a_custom_taxonomy)

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked just fine! Only last question I have is how I can filter the posts by term on each "category". So right now just like you posted the `taxonomy-event_type.php` template is used for my taxonomy. When I call `/event_type/lectures` I use a simple query `$loop = new WP_Query( $args );` to get all posts. However on the `lectures`-page I only want to see/filter all lectures from this taxonomy. Any idea how I can filter this within the same taxonomy-event_type.php template? Thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly but you should let wordpress do the query. When you call /event_type/lectures wordpress has already filtered the posts for you and you just have to output them. (for example: while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); the_title(); endwhile; )

Comment: Thank you, didn't know wordpress handles this automatically!

Answer (score 1):

```
   function wp_list_tax_terms($tax = 'category',$order,$hide_empty = FALSE){
    $terms = get_terms( $tax, array(
        'orderby'    => $order,
        'hide_empty' => $hide_empty
     ));
     if ( $count > 0 ){
     echo '<ul>';
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       echo '<li><a href="'.$term->name.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';   
     }
     echo '</ul>';
  }    
}
```